# Writing a publisher node

Tags: rviz, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I write some publisher node that computes some coordinates and publishes their position.

How do I transform from a fixed frame like /world to another frame of my choice like /sat1/base_link. I believe tf broadcaster is required for it. Can anybody help me in this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69772/writing-a-publisher-node/) by [Gudjohnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/5370/gudjohnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please, check these tutorials:

[tutorial for publisher/subscriber](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

[tutorial for frame transformation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29)

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3